# How to add harbor registry in containerd

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, harbor, rhel8

Does anyone know how can we add harbor registry to containerd cri . I have added it as insecure registry but kubernetes is not able to pull harbor images .
[image for the error that i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ2u8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how you installed and configured Harbor? Helm? which one?
I would suggest use [bitnami harbor](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/bitnami/harbor)

[EKS installation example](https://ruzickap.github.io/k8s-harbor/part-04/#install-harbor-using-helm)

[Issue #1238 kubernetes can't pull image from Harbor](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/1238) suggest you to follow [Configuring Nodes to authenticate to a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry)